# OleDbException was unhandled by user code in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbexception

Here is the cs file:

```
public int CheckExisting(String sqlDbQry, String sTable)
    {
        Qry = sqlDbQry;
        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        con.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(Qry, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
            rQry = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
        con.Close();
        return rQry;
    }
```

Here is my another cs:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (objAdmin.CheckExisting("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration where Email='" + Textemail.Text.Trim() + "'", "Temp") > 0)
            {
                lblmail.Text = "Your EmailId already Registered, Please Login!";
                return;
            }
            if (objAdmin.CheckExisting("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration where Phone_num='" + Textphone.Text.Trim() + "'", "Temp") > 0)
            {
                lblmail.Text = "Mobile number already exists, Please Login!";

                return;
            }
}
```

When i enter input details and hit submit, it shows error something like this,

Here is the error of [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp6I4.jpg)

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I m using msaccess..

Comment: You still have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: sorry, i can't understand..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I m not using sql server, i created database in msaccess..

Comment: Use `try{} catch (OleDbException ex){}` on your code, then try tofind the sql vulnerability.

Comment: I m new to .net, can you please elaborate it, where can i add try and catch? thanks

Comment: 1. try the sql directly in the database to see if it works. 2. Put `try/catch` around the `ExecuteReader`. 3. Exception details? The screen shot does not show any details.

Comment: SQL injection applies to any SQL statement; it has nothing to do with SQL Server.

Comment: so, what can i follow your instructions..

Comment: Stop and do some research. [Here is a place to start perhaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes there is an SQL injection issue, but that is secondary.

Comment: @radarbob: That screenshot could show the error..

Comment: @radarbob: I can't understand which you provided link, can please elaborate... thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are manually building a sql string from a textbox labeled "email".  Email addresses usually contain an "@".  Because you are building a raw sql query you are putting the "@" directly in to the query.  `OleDb` interprets that as a SQL parameter, and expects you to supply it, which you are not, which is what is causing the error.  You will get a similar error if any of your text boxes contain a ' (single quote).

You should look in to using [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and [OleDbParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass in your parameters instead of sending raw strings.  This will also fix your sql injection attack vulnerability that others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I can't edit your post so I'm doing it here.

```
public int CheckExisting(String sqlDbQry, String sTable)
{
    try
    {
        Qry = sqlDbQry;
        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        con.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(Qry, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
            rQry = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
        con.Close();
        return rQry;
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        string message = ex;
        //put your message on a texbox or alert handler error on the web
        //or while debugging use a breakpoint on the exception handler
        //use log
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Keep in mind that with OleDb, parameters are positional, not named. You can name your parameters, but you cannot use the @ syntax in your command (it throws an error about needing to declare a scalar variable) ... the correct syntax is to use the ? ... and it will take the parameters in the order in which you've added them.
>
> Also, I prefer the .AddWithValue syntax, which is even more readable, I think.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (objAdmin.CheckExisting("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration where Email='" + this.Textemail.Text.Trim() + "'", "Temp") > 0)
        {
            lblmail.Text = "Your EmailId already Registered, Please Login!";
            return;
        }
        if (objAdmin.CheckExisting("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration where Phone_num='" + this.Textphone.Text.Trim() + "'", "Temp") > 0)
        {
            lblmail.Text = "Mobile number already exists, Please Login!";

            return;
        }
```

}

> Just put this.Textemail.Text and this.Textphone.Text , i hope so it will be helpful for you.

Comment: He added `this` before all of the control references, which does nothing, since it is there implicitly.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: all answers didn't help me and your answer, can't able to follow.. because i can't understand.. :(

Comment: I'll try and make an example for you